# Why I can't manipulate returned object from promise inside then?

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I have and Promise that return an object and I would like to loop thorough it to sort by prices but I can't manipulate the returned object and I don't know why.

If I just `console.log` the result like I did on second console.log it shows the values but if I do anything That I founded on the web they return empty array.

This is my code:

```js
getPrices().then(res => {
    console.log(typeof res);
    // console -> object
    console.log('result', res);
    // console -> [] {0: {price: "12.80", competitor: "competitor 1")...} length: 7 __proto__: Array(0)
    console.log('stringfy', JSON.stringify(res));
    // console -> stringfy []
    console.log('array from', Array.from(res));
    // console -> [] length: 0 __proto__: Array(0)
    console.log('object keys', Object.keys(res));
    // console -> [] length: 0 __proto__: Array(0)
});
```

I also tried using `Object.entries` and using `map` direct on `res`

**How is the right way to convert this object to array and use .sort or .map?**

And this is my gitPrice function:

```js
export const getPrices = async () => {
    const prices = [];
    data.map(index => {
        request(index.link, (error, response, html) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                let che, price, newItem;
                che = cheerio.load(html);
                price = (index.selector.includes("itemprop")) ? che(index.selector).attr('content') : che(index.selector).text();
                newItem = {
                    "price": price,
                    "competitor": index.competitor
                };
                prices.push(newItem);
            } else {
                console.error(`ERROR ${response.statusCode}: Was not possible to scrape the ${index.competitor}: `)
            }
        });
    });
    return prices;
}
```

Comment: The first log to console log is misleading you. At that moment `res` is probably empty, but at the time you look at the console and click on that log item to inspect it, it has already been populated by some other async process triggered from within `getPrices`. `console` is async. If you really need to know the "current" value, use `JSON.stringify`. My guess is that the implementation of `getPrices` is wrong so that the promise it returns is resolved too soon. Possibly you have a call to an async API in there, that you are not awaiting.

Comment: @trincot I added my `getPrice` function. Could you please confirm what's wrong?

Comment: And yes, my guess was right. Now that you posted that code it is clear that you do no wait for the callbacks of `request` to actually execute. An `async` function without the `await` keyword is often a sign of a bug.

Comment: @trincot I've been trying some ways to add await and none worked. Where is the right place? I already add before `data.map` and on `return await prices`

Comment: You need first to have a promise. Promisify `request`. What is `request`? Can you point to documentation or implementation? Possibly there is already a promisified alternative for it.

Comment: @trincot I'm using cheerio to scraping website. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: You can't use synchronous function `.map` to expect asynchronous result even after you use `await` inside the `.map` callback. Try using `for...of` loop and use await inside the loop.

Comment: Is `request` a function exposed by cheerio? Can you point me to its documentation? Are you sure it is not coming from the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package? (Yong Quan, he first needs to promisify...)

Comment: @trincot this is the problem, they don't have a good documentation. I following some examples and all of them use `request` to access the website and inside of it they are calling `cheerio.load`. You can see more here: https://cheerio.js.org/. Before post here I tried to do it with promise but unsuccessful as I'm new using promises.

Comment: I see you already accepted an answer, so I'll leave it at that. NB: a promise enabled API for `request` makes things easier.

Comment: @trincot Thanks mate, I will have a look o this. And that solution is returning with 7 positions but all undefined. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common beginner problem, you trying to get array of result, but you should get array of promises, and then resolve them all

```
export const getPrices = () => {
    const prices = [];
    const dataPromises = data.map(index => { // this contains array of promises
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request(index.link, (error, response, html) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                let che, price, newItem;
                che = cheerio.load(html);
                price = (index.selector.includes("itemprop")) ? che(index.selector).attr('content') : che(index.selector).text();
                newItem = {
                    "price": price,
                    "competitor": index.competitor
                };
                resolve(newItem); // resolve the value
            } else {
                reject(new Error(`ERROR ${response.statusCode}: Was not possible to scrape the ${index.competitor}: `))
            }
          });
       })
    });
    return Promise.all(dataPromises); // resolve all
}
```

Comment: Looks good mate. I tried it, no errors and I can manipulate the result but the values inside of array are undefined.

Comment: I edit your answers changing `const dataPromises` by `prices.push` and when `return Promise.all(dataPromises)` I used `return Promise.all(prices)` and then worked perfect for me. Really thanks for your help!